# Texturing a quad

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering

Drawing a quad with a texture mapped to it with the fixed OpenGL pipeline is one of the easiest things to do in OpenGL.

And for some madmaking, mysterious, dumb reason I can't get it to work.

I loaded a texture through Slick:

```
texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/textures/texture.png"), false);
```

I setup my 2D projection:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then in my game loop I call:

```
texture.bind();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0, 0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(300, 0);

glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(300, 90);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0, 90);

glEnd();
```

This is my texture:

[image: Madmaking]

And this is what I get:

[image: Madmaking]

It's smaller, and as you can see it's all wrong.
It's kind of embarrassing that I have to ask this question, but it has keeping me busy for a few hours now.

Comment: Have you tried rendering it with colors instead of a texture in order to see what pixels are actually being rendered? Also, you should set your texture environment (clamp mode, filtering, etc).

Comment: Yes, it renders from the top left to the bottom right (where the green line ends). I tried setting up the texture environment already, no change though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s likely that when loaded by your framework, the texture is padded vertically and horizontally to the nearest power of two. For instance, if it’s a 320×200 image, it will be stored in a 512×256 texture.

You have at least two options:

- use a texture with power of two dimensions
- or change your texture coordinates to the proper ones, for instance `glTexCoord2f(320.f / 512, 200.f / 256);`.

Comment: Unbelievable. That sucks, Slick! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Its good for you, by default OpenGL cant handle non power-of-two textures, so you would have to pad them yourself to the next power of two, its just doing the hard work for you.